# Rebasing a branch with another parent branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I have my master branch as `commitA` <- `HEAD`

dev branch as `commitA` -> `commitB` -> `commitC`<- `HEAD`

feature branch taken from master as `commitA` -> `commitD` <- `HEAD` and pushed it to remote.

I have created the `feature` branch wrongly from `master` instead of creating it from `dev`.

Now I want to make my feature branch to look like `commitA` -> `commitB` -> `commitC` -> `commitD`<- `HEAD`, So I have done a rebase:

```
git rebase dev
```

The local branch looks like what I need now. But when I push it to remote, It is getting rejected with

```
! [rejected]          feature -> feature (non-fast-forward)
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I tried a `git pull`, Which makes the local branch looks something like:

`commitA` -> `commitB` <- `HEAD`. and it does not make any sense to me. So How can I fix my original problem of making my feature branch in remote to be `commitA` -> `commitB` -> `commitC` -> `commitD`<- `HEAD`

Comment: Instead of pulling, you should have pushed with `--force-with-lease` to replace the previous history (``A - D``) with the new one (`A - B - C - D'`). In a nutshell.

Comment: Yes. This works. I should force push it. You can post this as answer. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**
Instead of pulling, you should have pushed with `--force-with-lease` to replace the previous history (`A - D`) with the new one (`A - B - C - D'`).